# elseif statement on array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run an elseif statement on a variant array, but I cannot get the ElseIf statement to work, it only runs on the initial if and else clause but it ignores the second elseIf statement. The result I am currently getting is that column BN will be populated with Type 1 and Type 3, but Type 2 seems to be completely ignored.

I tried it initially on an if for loop, but it was incredibly slow, whilst this is a lot faster.

What am I missing here?

```
Sub test()
   Dim ary As Variant, nary As Variant
   Dim r As Long
   
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
      ary = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2
   End With
   
   ReDim nary(1 To UBound(ary), 1 To 1)
   
   With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For r = 1 To UBound(ary)
         If ary(r, 1) Like "*AAA*" Or ary(r, 1) Like "*AAA 22*" Then
            nary(r, 1) = "Type 1"
         ElseIf ary(r, 1) Like "*BBB*" Then
            nary(r, 1) = "Type 2"
         Else
            nary(r, 1) = "Type 3"
         End If
      Next r
      
   End With
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("BN2").Resize(r).Value = nary
End Sub
```

Comment: The `or` clause looks redundant. Anyway what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @SJR the problem is that the 'ElseIf ary(r, 1) Like "*BBB*" Then' statement seems to be ignored when I run the code, as the output in column BN doesnt generate a type 2 even though it should.

Comment: Maybe it is ignored. Without seeing any data, no idea what is going on.

Comment: Please post some sample data that you expect to return Type 2

Comment: You might want to pay attention to this line 'ary = .Range("I2", .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2',  Did you check in the Locals window what actually get put into Ary.

Comment: few things 1. the or is redundant, be careful if anything has an AAA in it it will be Type 1 irrespective of it it has a BBB.  2.  this is case sensitive so bbb or BbB will not be seen.  3. i get a final #N/A from the ouput I think `resize(r)` should be `resize(r - 1)`.  Otherwise the code works for me

Comment: tried the code as-is, and is working fine, maybe there's issues with your data or some sort of conditional formatting from a previous attempt of solving the issue at hand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH7SZ.png

Comment: I'm with tnavidi here - can you show your sample data that you're using this on which is failing?

Answer (score 0):

### Looking for Substrings Using `Instr`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    
    Dim ary() As Variant ' assuming there is at least two cells!
    ary = ws.Range("I2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).Value
    
    Dim nary() As String: ReDim nary(1 To UBound(ary), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(ary)
        cString = CStr(ary(r, 1))
        If InStr(1, cString, "AAA", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' contains
            nary(r, 1) = "Type 1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, cString, "BBB", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' contains
            nary(r, 1) = "Type 2"
        Else
            nary(r, 1) = "Type 3"
        End If
    Next r
       
    ' At this point 'r = UBound(ary) + 1'!
       
    ws.Range("BN2").Resize(r - 1).Value = nary

End Sub
```